# Angular2 Get Request throws 406 Http Error

Tags: javascript, angular, http, header, http-status-code-406

Here we go again. I'm getting a 406 as a Response from a angular client call.

This time I have a problem on my logging.component.ts in my Angular 2 app.

The app rely on a rest application (spring boot) that comunicate via rest controllers.

I've noticed that requesting data from controller via rest client like postman doesn't throw any issue.

So the problem must be in the front-end.

This is the component code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Http, RequestOptions, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {AppHTTPService} from '../../../login/appHTTP.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Cookie} from "ng2-cookies";


@Component({selector: 'app-logging', templateUrl: './logging.component.html', styleUrls: ['./logging.component.scss']})


export class LoggingComponent implements OnInit {

  p : number = 1;
  logsRes;
  logs;
  individualLog = [];
  logSelezionato = false;

  private componentUrl = this.service.resourceUrl + "logging/";

  constructor(private service: AppHTTPService, private http : Http, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLogs();
  }
//THIS IS THE METHOD CALLED FROM COMPONENT
  viewLog(name) {

      let access = Cookie.get('access_token');
      let headers = new Headers({
          'Accept':'application/json',
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer' + access
      });
      const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

      this
          .http
          .get(this.componentUrl + name,options)
          .map((res) => res.json())
          .subscribe(data => {
              this.individualLog = data;
          });

      this.logSelezionato = true;
  }

  getLogs() {
    this
      .service.getResource(this.componentUrl)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.logsRes = data;
        this.logs = this.logsRes;
      });
  }
}
```

**Let me show you the html component that use the output via ngFor**

```
<app-page-header [heading]="'Log'" [icon]="'fa-user'"></app-page-header>

<div class="row user__nav">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <nav class="user__navigation">

            <ul class="user__tabs">

            </ul>

        </nav>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row display large-padding">
        <div class="col-lg-3">


            <table class="table  table-striped table-hover">



                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="table__utility"><input type="checkbox" name="shouldDelete" [checked]="isChecked"/>&nbsp;</th>


                        <th>Log message</th>


                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                <tr *ngFor="let log of logsRes"> 

<td><input type="checkbox" name="shouldDelete" [checked]="isChecked"/>&nbsp;</td>


                    <td><a (click)="viewLog(log.name)">{{log.name}}</a></td>

                </tr>
                </tbody>               

            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-9" *ngIf="logSelezionato">

            <table class="table log-table table-striped table-hover">

                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th class="log-date_head">Date</th>

                        <th>Log message</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
<tbody>
                <tr class="log-date_body" *ngFor="let singleLog of individualLog | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 25, currentPage: p}"> 

       <td>{{singleLog.logDate}}</td>    
                   <td><a>{{singleLog.logMessage}}</a></td>                   
                </tr>
</tbody>        
            </table>
            <pagination-controls class="pagination-controls" (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**And in the following image you can see the chrome console error**

[Console error : http 406](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rbop1.png)

I've googled a lot but I can't find similar issues. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

HI Header should be use **append method**

```
 let headers = new Headers()
 headers.append('Accept','application/json')
 headers.append('Content-type','application/json')
 headers.append('Authorization','Bearer' + access)
 this.http.get(this.componentUrl + name,{ headers: headers})
          .map((res) => res.json())
          .subscribe(data => {
              this.individualLog = data;
          });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that not solve the problem but is an elegant programming common use.